# Grafico de Curva Genetic Algorithm (Python)

Tags: python-3.7, optimización

estoy intentando encontrar el error de este código en la cual el gráfico (visualización) no muestra la evolución de la curva de convergencia. El código optimiza la función en forma correcta y corre, pero no hay caso con la gráfica. Muchas gracias! (Estoy usando Spider).

```
    import numpy as np
    import ga
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Conditions, definitions and applications

    no_variables = 2
    pop_size = 100
    crossover_rate = 50
    mutation_rate = 50
    no_generations = 300
    lower_bounds = [-512, -512]
    upper_bounds = [512, 512]
    step_size = 5
    rate = 10
    pop = np.zeros((pop_size, no_variables))
    for s in range(pop_size):
        for h in range(no_variables):
            pop[s,h] = np.random.uniform(lower_bounds[h], upper_bounds[h])
    
    extended_pop = np.zeros((pop.size + crossover_rate + mutation_rate + 2*no_variables * rate, pop.shape[1]))

    # Visualization
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    fig.show()
    plt.title('Evolutionary process of the objective function')
    plt.xlabel('Iteration')
    plt.ylabel('Objective function')

    A = []
    a = 5 
    g = 0
    global_best = pop
    k = 0

    while g <= no_generations:
        for i in range(no_generations):
            offspring1 = ga.crossover(pop, crossover_rate)
            offspring2 = ga.mutation(pop, mutation_rate)
            fitness = ga.objective_function(pop)
            offspring3 = ga.local_search(pop, fitness, lower_bounds, upper_bounds, 
            step_size, rate)
            step_size = step_size * 0.98
            if step_size < 1:
                step_size = 1
            extended_pop[0:pop_size] = pop
            extended_pop[pop_size:pop_size + crossover_rate] = offspring1
            extended_pop[pop_size + crossover_rate:pop_size + crossover_rate + 
            mutation_rate] = offspring2
            extended_pop[pop_size + crossover_rate + mutation_rate:pop_size + 
            crossover_rate + mutation_rate + 2*no_variables*rate] = offspring3
            fitness = ga.objective_function(extended_pop)
            pop = ga.selection(extended_pop, fitness, pop_size)
            print("Generation: ", g, ", Current fitness value: ", 10e6- 
            max(fitness))
            A.append(10e6-max(fitness))
            g += 1
            if i >= a:
                if sum(abs(np.diff(A[g-a:g]))) <= 0.05:
                    index = np.argmax(fitness)
                    current_best = extended_pop[index]
                    pop = np.zeros((pop_size, no_variables))
                    for s in range(pop_size):
                        for h in range(no_variables):
                            pop[s, h] = np.random.uniform(lower_bounds[h], 
                            upper_bounds[h])
                    step_size = 5
                    global_best[k] = current_best
                    k += 1
                    break
        
                #Visualization
                ax.plot(A, color='r')
                fig.canvas.draw()
                ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, g - no_generations), right=g + 3)
                if g > no_generations:
                    break
             if g > no_generations:
                 break
        fitness = ga.objective_function(global_best)
        index = np.argmax(fitness)
        print("Best solution = ", global_best[index])
        print("Best fitness value =", 10e6-max(fitness))
        plt.show()
```

Este algoritmo sirve para la optimización de una función específica. Como se explico anteriormente, funciona bien y optimiza en forma correcta (ejecuta), sin embargo en la parte de visualization (que esta indicado en el código) no logra graficar la curva de convergencia como debería, desconozco si es problema de Spider o hay algún detalle que me falta.

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? ¿Cual es el resultado "correcto"?

Comment: Buenas. Ese algoritmo no es Simmulated Annealing, es Genetic Algorithm (o algoritmo genético) aunque pertenecen al mismo conjunto de problemas, los metaheurísticos, son distintos algoritmos.

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo que edites y mejores tu pregunta, quitando todo el código excepto la función encargada de gráficar y pongas solo esa función con el input que tiene y el tipo de gráfica que deseas (será un line chart imagino con el mejor resultado de cada generación)

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente me habia confundido. Ahora edite el codigo, muchas gracias.